# IE 11 iframe redirect without history (back button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe that I use to display PDF files. The UI application is on my dev.domain.com location, while the pdf files are hosted on devapi.domain.com. My main issue is that I want to be able to change what PDF file is being viewed, but I don't want the browser back button to influence the content of the iframe. In Google Chrome, this works wonderfully:

```
$('#preview-frame')[0].contentWindow.location.replace(url);
```

I just do this when I need to change the PDF, and all is well and good. In IE11, however, I get access denied errors when running the above to change PDFs. Any suggestions on how to change the content of the iframe without influencing back button behavior on all major browsers?

Comment: Could you try creating a new iframe?

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing that. I'm using angular, so I just made pseudo-iframe element directive. When I change the src attribute on my fake iframe, it clears out its contents, then creates a new iframe with the new src. That seems to work in every browser I have tested so far.